# Vb.Net get last auto increment value in data table

Tags: vb.net, get, increment

I am loading data from access database from a datatable name car table. This table has the carId  as an auto increment number[image]

loading data this way:

```
Private Sub frmCar_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    Try
        dsDataSet = New DataSet
        loadCars()

        bsCar = New BindingSource(dsDataSet, "car")

        CarIDTextBox.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("text", bsCar, "carId"))
        BrandTextBox.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("text", bsCar, "brand"))
        ModelTextBox.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("text", bsCar, "model"))
        RegNoTextBox.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("text", bsCar, "regNo"))
        InsIDTextBox.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("text", bsCar, "insId"))
        DailyChargeTextBox.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("text", bsCar, "dailyCharge"))
        WeeklyChargeTextBox.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("text", bsCar, "weeklyCharge"))
        MonthlyChargeTextBox.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("text", bsCar, "monthlyCharge"))
        YearlyChargeTextBox.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("text", bsCar, "yearlyCharge"))
        TransmissionTextBox.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("text", bsCar, "transmission"))
        ColorTextBox.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("text", bsCar, "color"))
        RemarkTextBox.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("text", bsCar, "remark"))


    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(Err.Description)
    End Try
End Sub

Sub loadCars()
    Dim sql As String

    Try
        oledbConn = New OleDbConnection(oledbConnString)
        oledbConn.Open()

        sql = "select * from car order by carId"
        daCar = New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, oledbConn)
        daCar.Fill(dsDataSet, "car")
        '----------------------------------------------------------------------

        oledbConn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        oledbConn.Close()
        MsgBox(Err.Description)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub btnNew_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnNew.Click
    Try
        bsCar.AddNew()

    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(Err.Description)
    End Try
End Sub

Private Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    Try
        Me.Validate()
        bsCar.EndEdit()
        daCar.Update(dsDataSet.Tables("car"))
        MsgBox("Car saved successfully")
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(Err.Description)
    End Try
End Sub
```

Now When I add a new car and save it, everything works perfect. But I need the carId of the new car added to be displayed immediately after adding. How can I do that without querying the database? Thank you

Comment: Without querying to the database? You can't (With Access at least).

Comment: As Steve said with Access you will need to Query the DB again. Basically send a Query to Select carID where regNo = the regNo you just added. In hind site as regNo would be unique (unless you ar transferring plates from car to car) then regNo could have been the primary key and you would not need an AutoNumber field.

Comment: Access supports the `SELECT @@IDENTITY` to get the last autoincrement generated but the problem here is the Adapter.Update command that doens't give us an open connection to work with. Need to do some test

Comment: Those are very useful notes. I think the solution of Mr. Steve makes things clear. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that there is way to get the AutoIncrement value from the database during the excution of Update method, but there is no way to avoid another query to the database.
You can use the [`RowUpdated`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter.rowupdated%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) event raised by the `OleDbDataAdapter` after a row has been updated (or inserted).

We need to use the "SELECT @@IDENTITY" command supported by Access, but this cannot be effective if we don't work on the same connection used by the Update thus the only option is to use the `RowUpdated` event where the connection is still open

```
' Need to have a OleDbCommandBuilder to build the InsertCommand for the OleDbDataAdapter
Sub loadCars()
    ....
    daCar = New OleDbDataAdapter(sql, oledbConn)
    Dim builder = new OleDbCommandBuilder(daCar)
    daCar.InsertCommand = builder.GetInsertCommand
    daCar.Fill(dsDataSet, "car")
End Sub


' In the update code
AddHandler daCar.RowUpdated, New OleDbRowUpdatedEventHandler(AddressOf NewRowInserted)
daCar.Update(dsDataSet.Tables("car"))

' The event handler is called for any row inserted, updated or deleted
Sub NewRowInserted(sender as Object, e as OleDb.OleDbRowUpdatedEventArgs)

    ' Check if we are working for a row with the proper state
    If e.Row.RowState = DataRowState.Added Then
       Dim cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT @@IDENTITY",e.Command.Connection)
       Dim newID = DirectCast(cmd.ExecuteScalar(), Integer)
       Console.WriteLine(newID)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: But one more point here: Can I use the `AddHandler daCar.RowUpdated, New OleDbRowUpdatedEventHandler(AddressOf NewRowInserted)` for more than one adapter?